# Spring Data JPA: findOne with a unique key

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In Spring Data JPA, is there any simple repository query that returns one object, like `findOne(Integer id)` except by using other unique key columns' values?

something like `findOneByName(String name)` ..

Or should I just use JPQL Query?

Comment: if your colum is unique you will get only one object, for example, in your case, if name column is unique then a method findByName will retrieve only  one object.

Comment: @duardito cool thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query over your method in your repository .

for example

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

@Query("select u from User u where u.emailAddress = ?1")
User findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
}
```

Read more [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

Comment: You don't event need the @Query annotation as JPA will find the object through the method name. If emailAddress is unique you can name the method findFirstByEmailAddress and JPA will do all the magic. (At least if u extend org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository)

Comment: @natronite That's not JPA though, is it? I think it's some part of Spring that provides that "magic".